# Node.js: can't call one Javascript prototype method from another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I'm trying to define a class with two public methods. It so happens that one of the methods is useful for implementing the other one, but for the life of me, I cannot get that function to be recognized within the scope of the other one. I have no idea whether this is something specific to node.js or not, but in case it matters, this is running under node.

Here is a short toy problem which reproduces the behavior I'm seeing:

```
function Foo() {
    this.list = [];
}

Foo.prototype = {
    addSeveral: function(arr) { arr.forEach(function(v) { addOne(v)} ) },
    addOne: function(item) { list.push(item); }
}

f = new Foo();
f.addSeveral([1,2,3]);
```

When I run this, it blows up with:

```
[jasonb@localhost]$ node testobj.js

/home/jasonb/work/testobj.js:6
Foo.prototype.addSeveral = function(arr) { arr.forEach(function(v) { addOne(v)}
                                                                     ^
ReferenceError: addOne is not defined
    at /home/jasonb/work/entity_mapping/testobj.js:6:70
```

I've tried every variation I can find on how to assign stuff to a class's prototype, with the same results. And if I try to call `this.addOne(v)` instead, it still blows up, but with `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addOne'`

How can I call `addOne()` within `addSeveral()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `forEach` invokes a callback function for each element of the array, you're losing context (`this` is not the `Foo` object inside your callback).  You can close over a reference:

```
Foo.prototype = {
    addSeveral: function(arr) { var self=this; arr.forEach(function(v) { self.addOne(v)} ) },
    addOne: function(item) { this.list.push(item); }
}
```

...or just use a regular loop, which will have **much** better performance – function invocation is expensive.

```
addSeveral: function(arr) { for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) this.addOne(arr[i]); };
```

Comment: No. As I said, if I prepend `this.` to the method names, it dies with a different error: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addOne'`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `this` to `forEach`:

```
addSeveral: function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (v) {
    this.addOne(v)
  }, this)
}
```

Or you can use bind:

```
addSeveral: function (arr) {
  arr.forEach((function (v) {
    this.addOne(v)
  }).bind(this))
}
```

But what I would do is `push.apply`:

```
addSeveral: function (arr) {
  [].push.apply(this.list, arr)
}
```